# Error Pre-Verifying class

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, midlet

I am using Eclipse Juno and `Jre7`. I'm also using `Java ME SDK 3.0` and I have tried `Java ME 8.1` too.

I have all the `JAR` files I need. The project works in a normal Java Project. But `midlet` project is creating the problem. So, the problem is not with the `JRE` or `eclipse`. It has something to do with `midlet` project. Could anyone tell me what could be the reason ? Is there a way to remove these errors ?

This is the error:

```
java.lang.String Error preverifying class java.lang.String
```

Comment: Are you using an Eclipse plugin? Which one?

Comment: No. I'm not using an eclipse plug in. Using JAVA ME(Micro edition)

Comment: Java code compiled by Eclipse will create class files based on JRE. Java ME SDK will deny these class files. Have you tried Antenna?

Comment: Uncaught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException:   0
 - com.sun.ams.TaskManagerHelperImpl.getTaskInfo(), bci=46
 - com.sun.ams.TaskManagerHelperImpl.startTaskWithOptions(), bci=29
 - com.sun.ams.TaskManagerExtImpl.startTask(), bci=6
 - com.sun.midp.odd.ODTEngineBase.runMIDletSuite(), bci=12
 - com.sun.midp.odd.InstallerListenerWithExecute$1.run(), bci=23
 - java.lang.Thread.run(), bci=5

Comment: ^ this is the exception I am encountering after build of J2ME application. I have no clue what is going on? The classes have built properly and packaged in a jar.

Comment: Your question was about a preverification issue. Now you add a comment about a NullPointerException... Did you preverification error stop?

Comment: Yes, When I used the proguard preverification settings, it builds without errors but at run time gives an exception.

Comment: So... your original question is not necessary, please, delete it.